# My Plugin dont overwrite the default values

Tags: jquery, plugins

I try to realise my first jquery plugin (Im a noob).

```
(function($){

    $.test = function(selector, settings){

        // settings

        var config = {
            'text': "test"
        };

        if ( settings ){$.extend(config, settings);}

        // variables

        var i = 0;
        alert(config.text);
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Calling

```
$.test("juhu");
```

The script should alert "Juhu" not the default value "test".
What is the fault?

Could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extend this way:

```
if (settings) { config = $.extend( {}, config, settings ); }
```

Then access the value with `config.text`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign the return value of `$.extend`. Try something like

```
function(selector, settings){
    var config = {
        'text': "test"
    };

    config = $.extend(config, settings || {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling

```
$.test("juhu");
```

but your function takes two parameters

```
$.test = function(selector, settings)
```

so "juhu" becomes the selector, settings is undefined which means if (settings) fails and the default "test" string is alerted.